# React js: Single page app with different css for each view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm doing server side rendering, and rendering the entire `<html/>` in react, including the `<head/>`.

Do I have to lump all of the CSS for each view into one big file?

Loading different view specific stylesheets by passing `.css` file locations as `props` into a `<head/>` react class seems like a good alternative, but how do I prevent styling conflicts when transitioning from one view to the next, since the styling for the old view will still linger in the browser?

Comment: Only using inline styling would circumvent this problem, but that would be such a rogue move!